# dnsmasq forwards queries to 2 servers instead of 1

Tags: linux, networking, dns, dnsmasq, debian-jessie

I'm having a small issue with dnsmsasq on debian-jessie, it seems to forward incoming DNS queries to 2 ports instead of 1.

**Background:**

Runs on a machine whose LAN IP is 192.168.0.10. Sits behind a home router. The home router is configured to forward DNS traffic to 192.168.0.10. That part works, I do see incoming traffic from the LAN onto this machine.

**dnsmasq configuration:**

```
>cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf | grep -v ^# | grep -v ^\s*$

domain-needed
bogus-priv
server=127.0.0.1#5053
cache-size=10000
```

My **resolv.conf** tells local processes to send DNS queries to dnsmasq

```
>cat /etc/resolv.conf

# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

And dnsmasq, if it can't answer from its cache, then forwards incoming DNS traffic to another service running locally and listening on port 5053 via the `server=127.0.0.1#5053` config. That service is something I build myself and it **does not** forward DNS queries to 8.8.8.8

This works but not the way I intended. DNS queries get answered properly. As expected, port 5053 shows traffic and even provides answers (though slower than GoogleDNS)

```
>tcpdump -l -n -i any '(port 5053) and (port 53)'

13:57:53.817522 IP 127.0.0.1.47207 > 127.0.0.1.53: 7494+ [1au] A? www.example.com. (44)   # dnsmasq receives a query from `dig www.example.com` running locally
13:57:53.818609 IP 127.0.0.1.5258 > 127.0.0.1.5053: UDP, length 44                        # dnsmasq forwards to local DNS Server listening on 5053
13:57:53.818970 IP 192.168.0.10.5258 > 8.8.8.8.53: 50849+ [1au] A? www.example.com. (44)  # dnsmasq forwards to 8.8.8.8 on port 53 (Google DNS)
13:57:53.862170 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 192.168.0.10.5258: 50849$ 1/0/1 A 93.184.216.34 (60)      # dnsmasq receives answer from 8.8.8.8
13:57:53.862559 IP 127.0.0.1.53 > 127.0.0.1.47207: 7494 1/0/1 A 93.184.216.34 (60)        # dnsmasq forwards answer to dig running locally
13:57:53.980238 IP 127.0.0.1.5053 > 127.0.0.1.5258: UDP, length 49                        # dnsmasq receives answer from local DNS Server
```

So it appears dnsmasq tee's DNS queries to both

- 127.0.0.1 on port 5053, and almost immediately after also forwards to
- 8.8.8.8 on port 53

Why, what's wrong with my dnsmasq configuration, I expected traffic only on port 5053?

And where is that 8.8.8.8 coming from. Yes I know that's Google DNS, but where is dnsmasq or linux getting that IP from and which config file can I edit to change that?

```
>grep -r 8\.8\.8\.8 /etc/*.conf
```

returns nothing.

Comment: How about `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: `>cat /etc/resolv.conf`
`# Generated by resolvconf`
`nameserver 127.0.0.1`